# Trying to update shared preference from a Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm building a custom ringtone selector for my app. The class is called `SoundPicker` and it extends `FragmentActivity`. What I'm trying to do is save the selected ringtone to my app's settings file.

Here is my code:

```
String selectedResource = "blablabla";
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("notifications_new_message", selectedResource);
editor.commit();
```

The problem is that I get an error, refering to the new string I'm trying to set - `selectedResource`

That's the error I get:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required:
>   'java.util.Set'
>
> putStringSet (String, java.util.Set) in
>   Editor cannot be applied to (String, java.lang.String)

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be careful, putString and putStringSet is different method, 
so use putString instead

> editor.putString("notifications_new_message", selectedResource);

Comment: How did I not notice that? I just wasted a whole hour trying to figure out what's going on here :facepalm:

Comment: You may need some rest haha

Answer (score 2):

**You are trying to set string but putStringSet accept 2nd argument of type set**

> use putString to store string value or create string set and use putStringSet

```
//To store string value
String selectedResource = "blablabla";
SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("notifications_new_message", selectedResource);
editor.commit();



//To Store string set
Set<String> hs = ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());

String selectedResource = "blablabla";

hs.add(selectedResource);

SharedPreferences sharedPref =         
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("notifications_new_message", hs);
editor.commit();
```